# Where to Purchase Physical Copies of Grothendieck's EGA, SGA, and FGA

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am really interested in purchasing the physical copies of Grothendieck's legendary books: EGA, SGA, and FGA. I could not find prices through Amazon or eBay, which makes me to suspect that foreign bookstores will sell them.  By any chance, do you know any website that I could order physical copies?

Comment: Grothendieck quite famously tried to prevent his works from being published by any big publisher, in a "Declaration of intent of non-publication." So you might struggle. There are scans around (also against his will, but harder to contain).

Comment: I would advice to go in the library if you are a student or if you're not download it somehow. The price of these books are really expensive. On the other hand, I guess it worth it (I knew an expert who told me he could spends weeks on few pages of SGA sometimes).

Answer (score 2):

French originals and translations are here"
[https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can buy the whole EGA collection from the IHÉS itself, in form of fascicles (warning: most certainly they only sell the first edition of EGA I, since the second one was produced by another publisher). As explained [here](https://www.ihes.fr/bibliotheque/publications-mathematiques/), you have to download [this form](https://nextcloud.ihes.fr/index.php/s/84xW6qpagEy2K7A), fill it with your data, circle the books that you want, and then send it to them.

The whole collection costs 229€, plus shipping costs. These can be very expensive: I live in Spain and they wanted to charge 133€ more for shipping, so I didn't buy anything.

As for SGA or FGA, I'm pretty sure you can only find them in the second-hand market. Since there aren't many in circulation, they're usually really expensive.